# Return the next upcoming date match from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a basket application with mysql ver. 5.6..
On the calendar of each team, I want to get if a game is the next upcoming game or not, returning 1 or 0 value.

I tried with this query, but if there is a game on the current day, it isn't considered; also, if there is a game, for example, the next month, also it isn't considered (I know that is it because I set an interval by week):

```
select home, away, 
(case when (score_home = 0 and score_away = 0) 
and (match_date between now() and date_add(now(), interval 7 day))
then 1 else 0 end) as is_next

from calendario

order by year(match_date) asc, month(match_date) asc, day(match_date) asc
```

**EDITED**
**SAMPLE DATA**

Please, take a look of this sample data. Why all columns are 0?

[image]

I tried this code proposed:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.DATA, C.IDCAMPIONATO, (C.DATA >= CURDATE() AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CALENDARIO C2 WHERE C2.DATA >= CURDATE() AND C2.DATA < C.DATA)) AS IS_NEXT
FROM CALENDARIO C
WHERE C.IDCAMPIONATO = 5
ORDER BY DATE(C.DATA) ASC
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I've done

Comment: why you need interval ?

Comment: Because I want that only one record will be "the next game"

Comment: What does "calendar for each team" mean?

Comment: That on the table there is a record for each team

Comment: Yes but if the next game is not within the next week is it next game ?

Comment: What do you mean @MohdAlomar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed on your sample data that you have a got a column ID. Is this column Auto-Inc? If yes, you can use its potentiality like this:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.DATA, C.IDCAMPIONATO,
(CASE WHEN CAL.ID = (SELECT C2.ID FROM CALENDARIO C2 WHERE C2.DATA >= CURDATE() AND C2.IDCAMPIONATO = IDCA ORDER BY C2.DATA LIMIT 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IS_NEXT,
FROM CALENDARIO C
WHERE C.IDCAMPIONATO = 5
ORDER BY DATE(C.DATA) ASC
```

I think that you use the column "IDCAMPIONATO" to identify a team, correct?

Hope this help.

Comment: That's great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the filtering.  `now()` contains a time component.  You want `curdate()` instead and to check if any other game matches.  The following will tag the next game in `calendario`, which appears to be what you are asking for:

```
select c.*, 
       (c.match_date >= curdate() and
        not exists (select 1
                    from calendario c2
                    where c2.match_date >= curdate() and
                          c2.match_date < c.match_date
                   )
       ) as is_next
from calendario c
order by date(c.match_date) asc;
```

There are multiple things I don't understand about the question:

- Why are you including scores in the conditions?
- If you want this per team, why aren't you filtering on the team?
- What does this mean?  "On the calendar of each team, . . ."

You might want to ask another question, with sample data as text in the question, and a better description of your data and what you really want to do.

Comment: I included the score after tried a lot of queries, so I founded the best temporary solution for me. I already filter on the team, but if you see the example "MIAMI" compare more times. "On the calendar of each team" means that each team has got it's calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can add check if the match is not today and then since order by date you can limit 1 record to get the next match.

```
 select home, away, '1' as  is_next
from games where matchdate > now()
order by matchdate asc limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88ba84/2

Comment: No, I don't want to display only 1 record. I need all

Comment: Removed the limit 1 to get all records

Comment: Thank you but It isn't the result that I want. I want that only 1 record will be "IS_NEXT". See the sample data on the main post

Comment: let me create a sqlfiddel for you

Comment: Updated above, yes you don't need the score.

Comment: Thank you @Rehan but in your case, I don't have the list of other games

Comment: Then i think solution posted above works it will give u matches next day as next

Comment: I edited the main post. The code is near by the solution but check the sample data